# Python: Extract one value from a list of integers and lists

Tags: python, list

I have one list like this:

```
a = [3, 4, [1], 8, 9, [3, 4, 5]]
```

i would like to identify when that list with those characteristics has only one value, and then extract it to the main list:

Expected output

```
a = [3, 4, 1, 8, 9, [3, 4, 5]]
```

I know how extract values in a list composed of lists, but in this case i don't know how

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution is simple and straightforward:

```
result = []
for x in a:
   if isinstance(x, list) and len(x) == 1: # check item type and length
       result.append(x[0])
   else:
       result.append(x)
```

Or the same but one line

```
>>> [x[0] if isinstance(x, list) and len(x) == 1 else x for x in a]
[3, 4, 1, 8, 9, [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: @Levon it's identical to: `map(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) and len(x) == 1 else x, a)`.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I know (and like list comprehensions :-) and this solution was elegant so my upvote. I just think answers are more useful if they include more than just short solution code in case some readers aren't quite familiar with the more pythonic ways of solving problems. I see the answer has now been augmented in a helpful way. It's all good.